# There is no row at position 0 : While getting value from Dataset to Textbox in c#

Tags: c#, excel, dataset

I am trying to get value from excel's cell to textbox in c#. I have used dataset to get the value from excel , but when taking value from dataset to text box it give error

> There is no no row at position 0

I also tried using Item Array but no use .
Heres my code:

```
DataSet dsloc = new DataSet();
 OleDbDataAdapter daloc = new OleDbDataAdapter();
string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + txtfilepath.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
string strloc = "select * from [sheet1$A5:A5]";
OleDbCommand cmdloc = new OleDbCommand(strloc, con);
con.Open();
dsloc.Clear();
daloc.SelectCommand = cmdloc;
daloc.Fill(dsloc);
txtloc.Text = dsloc.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Location"].ToString();
```

I have tried

```
              DataRow drow;
              drow = dsloc.Tables[0].Rows[0];
              txtloc.Text = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
```

Also

```
   txtloc.Text = dsloc.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

My dataset shows there is value in it.[image]
But none of these work. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: The dataset is returning 0 records, or you are not hooking into Tables[0]. This is what the error means.

Comment: what do you mean by "you are not hooking into Tables[0]" ?

Comment: can you show your error messages? Also, are you planning on getting more than one table inside of the dataset? If you are only planning on bringing in one set of data (or 1 table) you could use DataTable instead which might help.

Comment: @Beengie actually i am trying to get only one cell's value onto textbox. I am not sure about datatable as I have to get value from excel so dont know how to achieve .

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the solution, the value coming from excel was actually the name of the column of the datatable as one can see on my screenshot, so I just need to get the column name.

```
 DataTable dtloc = new DataTable();
 string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + txtfilepath.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";
 string strloc = "select * from [sheet1$A5:A5]";
 OleDbCommand cmdloc = new OleDbCommand(strloc, con);
 con.Open();
 daloc.SelectCommand = cmdloc;

string location = dtloc.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString();
```

also used datatable instead of dataset.